# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined using ng-cropper directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm receiving `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.` When I attempt to load the ng-cropper directive, which is an angular binding for the cropper javascript image cropping library. I'm not entirely sure what code might be most relevant to show, but this is the top half of the directive:

```
angular.module('ngCropper', ['ng'])
.directive('ngCropper', ['$q', '$parse', function($q, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      options: '=ngCropperOptions',
      proxy: '=ngCropperProxy', // Optional.
      showEvent: '=ngCropperShow',
      hideEvent: '=ngCropperHide'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, atts) {
      var shown = false;

      scope.$on(scope.showEvent, function() {
        if (shown) return;
        shown = true;

        preprocess(scope.options, element[0])
          .then(function(options) {
            debugger;
            setProxy(element);
            element.cropper(options);
          })
      });

      function setProxy(element) {
        if (!scope.proxy) return;
        var setter = $parse(scope.proxy).assign;
        setter(scope.$parent, element.cropper.bind(element));
      }
```

The error is thrown on the `setter(scope.$parent, element.cropper.bind(element));` line in the `setProxy()` function.

It's because `cropper` apparently is undefined on the element variable. What would cause this? I am not an expert in angular directives, but I would imagine it should resolve fine if the tag has been setup like this?

and the strange thing is, it does resolve fine in the demo application and my code reflects the same setup! My only guess is perhaps another module I may be using could be interfering? I'm reluctant to take them all out but it might come down to that.

My modules are declared as:
`angular.module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngSanitize',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'angular.filter',
        'flow',
        'ng-sortable',
        'focus-if',
        'ngCropper',
        'controllers', 'services', 'directives', 'filters'])`

I referred to this demo to get as far as I did - https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper/tree/master/demo

I suppose,

1. On what basis should 'cropper' resolve? (so I know what to check)
2. Can you see any obvious issues with my code?

Comment: did you include jQuery in your html before angular ?

Comment: [Could not get error](http://plnkr.co/edit/iAYmhoR4WF52NLAy1cbM?p=preview) in your demo

Comment: Yes I know, the sample recreated does work. I appreciate the effort on making the plunker, there must be something further in my code is causing an issue. What generally speaking in angular would cause the `undefined` on the element variable? Where should cropper be defined for it to be picked up in that function?

Comment: @Arkantos Oh my gosh Arkantos, GENIUS! That was precisely the problem. Thanks so much, I guess I've had jquery running after angular for a while now because I didn't think to check that and must not have proved to be a problem until now. Submit this as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: Angular will work without `jQuery` to some extent with some limited API but the `CropperJS` that you were using is a jQuery plugin and `ngCropper` is merely a wrapper around `CropperJS`, so for the plugin to work properly, we should load `jQuery` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to maintain a precise order while loading your dependencies and jQuery should be loaded first before AngularJS and others as indicated in the sample HTML [here](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper/blob/master/demo/index.html).

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/cropper/dist/cropper.js"></script>
<link href="../bower_components/cropper/dist/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../ngCropper.js"></script>
```

Comment: Other than any solution that changes the jquery order? an existing project using the order like angular then jquery. also, if I changed the order it seems like getting another Typeerror like 'Cannot read property 'on''.